# How to calculate and display the Excel add-in panel total number of uses of all the macros included in this add-in

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry. Translated with Google translator!
Link to the website of the program developer, with which I created the file Excel add-in! This program is FREE!
[http://novikov.gq/products/ribbonxmleditor/ribbonxmleditor.html][1]

Initial data: we have an Add-in for the program Excel! The add-in consists of two macros that are associated with the buttons on the Add-in panel.

Task: summarize all the presses on the buttons. The amount of clicks to show in the Add-ons panel. The amount should not be reset after reboot.

Errors that I can not solve:
1) The amount of clicks is reset, if you select No (press button 2)
2) To the amount of clicks is added +1, every time the Excel is started - this is incorrect.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Init_RibVar_Custom">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="excel-vba" label="Test">
                <group id="groupe_1" label=" Редактирование">
                    <button id="button_1" imageMso="GoLtrDown" label="Button 1" onAction="macro1" />
                    <button id="button_2" imageMso="GoLtrDown" label="Button 2" onAction="macro2" />
                </group>

                <group id="groupe_2" label="Counter">
                    <labelControl id="Counter" getLabel="getLabel_Cnt" />
                </group>

            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Main code:

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If

Public MyCounter As Long
Public objRibCustom As IRibbonUI
Public cntr As IRibbonControl

Sub CheckRibbon()
    If objRibCustom Is Nothing Then
#If VBA7 Then
        Dim lPointer As LongPtr
        lPointer = CLngPtr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1"))
#Else
        Dim lPointer As Long
        lPointer = CLng(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1"))
#End If
        CopyMemory objRibCustom, lPointer, LenB(lPointer)
    End If
End Sub
Sub Init_RibVar_Custom(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set objRibCustom = ribbon
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = ObjPtr(ribbon)
    objRibCustom.Invalidate
    Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Input As #1
    Input #1, MyCounter
    Close #1
    MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
    Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
    Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, MyCounter
    Close #1
End Sub  
Sub getLabel_Cnt(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    Call CheckRibbon
    If cntr Is Nothing Then
        Set cntr = control
    End If
    label = "Counter: " & MyCounter
    On Error Resume Next
    objRibCustom.InvalidateControl control.ID
    objRibCustom.Invalidate
End Sub  
Sub macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
    MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
    Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
     MsgBox "First button", vbOKOnly
End Sub   
Sub macro2(control As IRibbonControl)
    MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
    Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
    If MsgBox("Second button ", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
Else
    End
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. This isn't a valid statement `MsgBox ("First button ", vbYesNo)= vbNo Then`

Comment: @ThunderFrame. Thanks,  fixed!

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of that counter is. You should [edit] your question to clarify exactly what the problem is, too. As it stands you described what's incorrect, but not what you're expecting instead.

Comment: In the ribbon's `onLoad` event procedure, you're doing `MyCounter = MyCounter + 1`, which adds `1` to `MyCounter` on restart, even though no button press. Is that what you expect?

Comment: @David Zemens. No, but I do not know how to fix it! This is the second mistake I can not cope with.

Comment: OK. That line is *clearly* adding 1 to the `MyCounter` every time the ribbon loads. If you don't want that to happen, what do you *think* you should do to that line?

Comment: You have an errant `End` statement attached to the `vbNo` response in button 2, this destroys all objects in memory. That is almost certainly *not* what you want to do here.

Comment: Delete this line!

Comment: That's what I would do :)

Comment: I created this operator intentionally, to show by example. In my main Add-on, there are a lot of places with the use of the operator End

Answer (score 1):

```
Public MyCounter As Long
```

That variable's value lives and dies with the execution context; this means when `End` runs, the value is gone. So you need a procedure that's reponsible for dealing with the file storage. Right now you have some of it in `Init_RibVar_Custom`; move that file-handling concern into its own procedure. Heck, move the whole counter-handling thing into its own class!

```
Option Explicit

Private currentValue As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    LoadValue
End Sub

Public Property Get Value() As Long
    Value = currentValue
End Property

Public Sub Increment()
    currentValue = currentValue + 1
    SaveValue
End Sub

Public Sub LoadValue()
    'assign currentValue from file
End Sub

Public Sub SaveValue()
    'save currentValue to file
End Sub
```

Now name that class something like `CallCounter`, and then instead of this:

```
Private MyCounter As Long
```

You can have this:

```
Private counter As New CallCounter
```

Now, all you have to do to keep a correct count is to call `counter.Increment` in your macros:

```
Sub macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
    counter.Increment
    '...
End Sub
```

Note that `Increment` will call `SaveValue`, so regardless of what happens, the correct value is always stored in the file.

Just make sure `LoadValue` and `SaveValue` don't change the value, and you'll always have the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for David Zemens and Mat's Mug

Solution of the problem number 1: Remove the End operator throughout the code
Solution of the problem number 2: Delete the line MyCounter = MyCounter + 1 from the procedure Init_RibVar_Custom

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If

Public MyCounter As Long
Public objRibCustom As IRibbonUI
Public cntr As IRibbonControl

Sub CheckRibbon()
    If objRibCustom Is Nothing Then
#If VBA7 Then
        Dim lPointer As LongPtr
        lPointer = CLngPtr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1"))
#Else
        Dim lPointer As Long
        lPointer = CLng(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1"))
#End If
        CopyMemory objRibCustom, lPointer, LenB(lPointer)
    End If
End Sub
Sub Init_RibVar_Custom(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set objRibCustom = ribbon
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = ObjPtr(ribbon)
    objRibCustom.Invalidate
    Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Input As #1
    Input #1, MyCounter
    Close #1
    Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
    Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, MyCounter
    Close #1
End Sub  
Sub getLabel_Cnt(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    Call CheckRibbon
    If cntr Is Nothing Then
        Set cntr = control
    End If
    label = "Counter: " & MyCounter
    On Error Resume Next
    objRibCustom.InvalidateControl control.ID
    objRibCustom.Invalidate
End Sub  

Sub macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Input As #1
Input #1, MyCounter
Close #1
MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
     MsgBox "First button", vbOKOnly
Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, MyCounter
Close #1
End Sub  

Sub macro2(control As IRibbonControl)
Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Input As #1
Input #1, MyCounter
Close #1
MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
    If MsgBox("Second button ", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
Else  
End If
Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, MyCounter
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: use hidden name. This hidden name is kept within workbook. To create hidden name (and also to re-initialize counter), run this procedure:

```
Sub CreateHiddenName()
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ClicksCounter", RefersTo:=0, Visible:=False
End Sub
```

The hidden name is safely kept in /xl/workbook.xml:

```
<definedNames>
    <definedName name="ClicksCounter" hidden="1">0</definedName>
</definedNames>
```

The test workbook I used had the following XML for ribbon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="OnRibbonLoaded">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="rxTab1" label="MY_TAB">
            <group id="rxGroup1" label="Group1">
                <button id="rxButton1"
                        label="I am humble button"
                        imageMso="QueryAppend"
                        onAction="OnHumbleButtonClick" />
            <labelControl id="rxLabel1"
                          getLabel="OnGetCounter" />
            </group>
        </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

VBA code (in standard module):

```
Private ribbon As IRibbonUI

Sub OnRibbonLoaded(IRibbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set ribbon = IRibbon
End Sub

Sub OnGetCounter(ctrl As IRibbonControl, returnValue)
    returnValue = "Counter: " & GetCounterValue()
End Sub

Sub OnHumbleButtonClick(ctrl As IRibbonControl)
    ' Do something here...
    ' In the end call:
    Call IncrCounter
End Sub

Sub IncrCounter()
    ThisWorkbook.Names("ClicksCounter").Value = GetCounterValue() + 1
    ribbon.InvalidateControl "rxLabel1"
End Sub

Function GetCounterValue()
    GetCounterValue = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Names("ClicksCounter").Value, "=", "")
End Function
```

What happens here in steps:

1) When workbook starts up, the **OnRibbonLoaded** is called whose sole purpose is to keep *IRibbonUI* variable.

2) When you press "humble" button, the **OnHumbleButtonClick** callback is run.

4) **OnHumbleButtonClick** runs **IncrCounter** procedure which:

4.1) increments counter;

4.2) invalidates *labelControl* to reflect new counter value (invalidating makes **OnGetCounter** to run to get new label for *labelControl*).

As a side note, it would be better to add code which would restore Ribbon variable address, if you, of course, use it. Here are required additions to code:

1) Create hidden name to keep address:

```
Sub AddNameForRibbonPointer()
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="RibbonPointer", RefersTo:=0, Visible:=False
End Sub
```

2) Declare Win32 **RtlMoveMemory** function which restores address:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If
```

3) Add a line which would keep ribbon's address in hidden name:

```
Sub OnRibbonLoaded(IRibbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set ribbon = IRibbon
    ThisWorkbook.Names("RibbonPointer").Value = ObjPtr(ribbon)
End Sub
```

4) Helper procedure to check whether ribbon variable is not nothing. If it is, then it will restore the address from hidden name:

```
Sub CheckRibbon()
     
    If ribbon Is Nothing Then
#If VBA7 Then
        Dim lPointer As LongPtr
        lPointer = CLngPtr([RibbonPointer])
#Else
        Dim lPointer As Long
        lPointer = CLng([RibbonPointer])
#End If
        CopyMemory ribbon, lPointer, LenB(lPointer)
    End If
 
End Sub
```

From now on, you just call **CheckRibbon** procedure before using ribbon variable:

```
Sub MyProcedure
    ' Doing something...
    Call CheckRibbon
    ribbon.Invalidate
End Sub
```

**UPD:**

To keep counter along with the workbook, you need, well, to save workbook. For usual workbook, you could either save it manually or do it automatically when closing workbook. For add-in you have to do it automatically because no changes are saved when you close Excel. For auto-saving you need to use Workbook's BeforeClose event. Go to ThisWorkbook module and paste this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```